# Saving multiple forms to a session without knowing input names

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms, session

```
    <form id="questions_1">
     <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="" data-content-theme="" id='q1'>
      <!-- GETS QUESTIONS FROM THE DATABASE -->
     </div>
    </form>
```

So I have a form that goes on for 5 pages like shown above, and I want to save all the data from each step, I am thinking something along the lines of this to pass all the data for each form into a .php page:

```
    function formSubmit1() {
     $("#questions_1").submit(function() {
      $.post('addToSession.php',$("#questions_1").serialize().function(data) {
      });
     return false;
     });
    }
```

By adding the following code to each "submit"/next page button I think I can call the function.

```
    <a data-role="button" href="#questions_2" onClick=formSubmit1()>Next</a>
```

This might need some customization but the part I am really unsure about is how do I get all the data without knowing their id's. The idea is to make the questions in this poll vary in order, size and questions so I need a general code that can handle any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$_REQUEST` to get data from forms on submit. After getting data `$_SESSION['name'] = $_REQUEST`.

Comment: Would that work when I don't know how many inputs I will have and what they are named? And are there a command that echoes all $_SESSION stored data?

Comment: use `print_r($_REQUEST);` and `print_r($_SESSION);` to see names and values.